# What google cloud setting could cause differences in speech to text

Tags: dialogflow-es

I have an odd issue. I have a dialogflow agent. Production is deployed with the same dialogflow agent zip. However, we have difference in behavior.

On dev, when we say "agent", dialogflow speech to text is interpreted as "agent".
On prod, when we say "agent", dialogflow speech to text is interpreted as "Hey Jen".

At first, I thought it was voice or a particular person's accent, but when multiple people call dialogflow and got the same result (getting "hey jen"). Since the dialogflow agent are essentially the same, what could have cause the difference in the voice to text interpretation between dev and prod? Are there some setting in the google cloud that could result in this difference?

Answer (score 0):

You can consider these options:

1)Enabling in the Production environment “auto speech adaptation”, which improves the speech recognition accuracy of the agent. You can see more [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/dialogflow/es/docs/speech-adaptation) about this feature.

2)Train your agent more. When your agent is trained, DialogFlow uses your training data to build machine learning models specifically for you agent. There is an automatic training agent or manual training agent. You can see more [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/dialogflow/es/docs/training).